# NodeJS, Javascript Chat; forEach array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

NodeJS script:

```
var rooms = [];

rooms.push({
    from: 'Chat-o-matic',
    allowedFor: 'everyone',
    name: 'Openbare kamer'
});

socket.emit('sendRooms', { value: rooms });
```

Client-JS:

```
function buildChat() {
    console.log("Build chat...");
    var rooms = [];
    socket.on('sendRooms', function(roomsocket) {
        console.log("Loading rooms...");
        roomsocket.forEach(function(data) {
            console.log(data.from);
        });
    });

    console.log(rooms);
    $( "#container" ).html("");
}
```

I want to show every 'from' from the array rooms @ ServerSide, but now I get this error on the client side:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'forEach'

What do I wrong? And how to fix it?

Comment: Objects have no length, and as such no forEach method. Use a for-in loop

Answer (score 3):

You are emitting an object. I guess you want to iterate over the `value`, that is an Array:

```
roomsocket.value.forEach(function(data) {
   console.log(data.from);
}):
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. As an beginner I did not saw this mistake.